# How to create Areas in real-time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am looking for a way to create MVC .NET Core Areas/sub-sites in realtime with code.  I am working on a project that requires dynamically created subsections for specific customized user experiences. Can .NET scaffolding work in real-time?  Is there a better way than scaffolding?

Comment: How do you expect scaffolding (a compiler tool) to work at runtime? Also, even if you could create areas in real time (it's quite easy in fact), you need controllers to handle those areas routes and views that must be served. You chose the wrong tool for this, so please tell us what you want to do rather than how

Comment: Camilo, Thank you for your quick response. As mentioned above, I am looking for a way to create MVC .NET Core Areas/sub-sites in realtime with code. I am working on a project that requires dynamically created subsections for specific customized user experiences. I am aware that controllers, views, and models will need to be created as well. I look forward to your answer as I am looking for an easy way to do this.